# Cannot get performance improvement with Haproxy

Tags: linux, performance, haproxy, performance-tuning

I have 4 web servers with a ruby web server running, and a server running haproxy.

I can get a RPS(request per second) of 300 against one web server using `ab`.

But I can only get a RPS of 340 against haproxy server.

The simple sample ruby app just provides one API that fetch certain ID from mysql and return to client.

And here's my haproxy conf

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     100000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
defaults
    log                     global
    maxconn                 1000000
frontend api
    bind *:8080
    mode http
    use_backend web
backend web
    balance     roundrobin
    mode http
    server 10.0.1.100:8080
    server 10.0.1.101:8080
    server 10.0.1.102:8080
    server 10.0.1.103:8080
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: What numbers do you get when you run `ab` against an individual ruby server?

Comment: I can get a RPS(request per second) of 300 against one web server using ab.

Comment: Have you tried running 4 instances of `ab`, or 4 instances of ab from 4 different IP's in front of haproxy?  Likely just one instance would utilize keep-alive and stay on one backend node.  Are you seeing equal distribution in the web console?

Comment: What value are you using for concurrency with ab? (`-c`)?  The numbers are pretty much meaningless unless this is set to *at least* the number of back-ends.  Default is 1.  Even your single server test result lacks meaning until you understand the impact of concurrent requests.

Comment: @Aaron I tried ab to 4 web servers at the same time, all gives a qps around 300

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot its `-c 10`